# Python multiprocessing is not asynchron

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using Python multiprocessing like this:

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=mp.cpu_count())
num_jobs = 5

print("Start Multiprocessing with: " + str(mp.cpu_count()) + " processes and " + str(num_jobs) + " jobs")

for i in range(num_jobs):
    start = int(...)
    end = int(...)
    result = pool.apply_async(worker, args = (parameter1, start, end, ), callback = callback_function)
    result.get()

result = pool.apply_async(worker2, args = (parameter1, parameter2, ), callback = callback_function2)
result.get()

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

In my worker functions I print sth like:

```
def worker(parameter1, start, end):

    for in_idx in range(0,100)
        print(in_idx)
```

However, the workers are called segmentally rather than asynchronously. What is wrong here? Any ideas?

Comment: you have `result.get` in the loop.

Comment: Is that a probem? I needed it for debugging reasons? Do I need to delete it or can you provide a solution without deleting it? @mgilson

Comment: get() by default blocks until completion.

Comment: Okay thank you! @jordanm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jordanm said:

> get() by default blocks until completion.